# Hermitian and skew operator?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Assume  $T$ has an eigenvalue $k$.

Then if $T$ is hermitian, then eigenvalue is real.

I don't understand this statement.

If $T$ is hermitian, does that mean that inner product is complex number?

In my book it says in the complex case $T$ is called hermitian and skew hermitian.

So inner product is complex but how can eigenvalue be real?

Answer (score 0):

Assume $T$ has some eigenvalue $k$ for some eigenvector $x$, then we know
$$ Tx = k x$$
In terms of inner products, we call $T$ hermitian if
$$ \langle Tx , y \rangle = \langle x , T^* y \rangle = \langle x , T y \rangle $$
Hence $T^* = T$. So what can we say about eigenvalues now? Well, we have
$$ k \langle x,x \rangle = \langle k x,x \rangle =\langle T x ,x \rangle = \langle x , Tx \rangle = \langle x, k x \rangle = \bar k \langle x,x \rangle $$
This implies that (where $\bar k$ is the complex conjugate of $k$)
$$ k = \bar k$$
which means that $k$ must be real.

Edit: If we're working in a nice vectorspace, we have
$$ \langle x,y \rangle = x^T \overline{y} $$
So if everything is real, we have $\overline{y} = y$ and then $\langle x,y \rangle$ must be real. In the case of complex $x,y$, this need not be the case ( but the norm is induced from it, and is real valued)

In the context of the above, we have Hermitian $A=\overline A ^{T} = A^* $. Thus if $A$ is real, we have that $A = \overline A$ so we obtain $A = A^T$(i.e. symmetric ). If $A$ is skew-Hermitian, this means $A = -A^*$, i.e. in the case that $A$ is real, we have $A = -A^T$ (skew-symmetric)

Comment: But if eigenvalue is real, does that mean inner proudct must be real? I believe that transformation is called hermitian in the complex case.

Comment: I have a question. In the real euclidian space transformations are called symmetry or skew symmetry. In the complex euclidean space, transformations are called hermitian and skew hermitian. Is above statement correct?

Comment: I made some edits, hopefully they answer your questions